# Web service providing zip code information for all states

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, webservice-client

I'm trying to write a web application that uses a web service to retrieve data about the zip codes in all States. The web services I have found tend to filter by State, leading me to create a loop of 50 requests and response parses to get the data I am after. I realize this is a terrible approach.

Are there any web services out there that anyone knows about that might provide the data I'm after?

I was trying to use: http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?placename=country=US&username=demo&maxRows=500

The problem here is max rows can't be greater than 500. With their paid account, it is raised to 1000. Still not even getting all the data I need in one request.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/) has a CSV of what looks to be all zip codes, with state information attached.